# What are the common causes of a high staff turnover?

Tags: human-resources, company-culture, united-kingdom

What are the common causes of high staff turnover, when there is no obvious cause (e.g. insolvency) ?

Comment: Bad working conditions, perhaps?

Comment: From experience, being the sucker that stuck around at an IT company for many years when the average employee was gone within a year or two: low pay.  Almost NOTHING else you do will matter if you underpay IT employees.

Comment: What answer other than "unhappy employees" do you expect to get? Your real question seems to be the one that was asked of your company's owner, which can only be answered by someone familiar with your company's inner workings. (Voted to close as company-specific.)

Comment: There is a large pool of academic litterature on this topic with interesting observations. I would suggest to reopen and include study based observations on that topic. see for example : http://www.lps-aix.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Griffeth-Gartner-2000.pdf or

Comment: Bad managers, being underpaid, and being bored/seeing no room for growth probably cover most preventable reasons. Circumstances will affect this too (especially people with family they want to move with or to be closer to).

Comment: In my experience, high staff turnover tends to lead to high staff turnover

Answer (score 9):

Two major reasons for high turnover that I have seen time and time again are:-

Pay is not competitive enough and jobs are easy to get.

and the even more frequent

BAD MANAGEMENT, usually if they're walking out the door not even bothering to give notice, it's the latter. One day I opened my machine, took out the hard drive (it was mine) and walked out the door and never went back. It was very unprofessional of me, but my treatment there was very unprofessional and I was probably half a step from physically assaulting a particular high up. If it was from colleagues I would have dealt with it differently, but sometimes things come to a head when it's superiors.

Something is very wrong at your company somewhere in the upper regions, it might just be one person creating the problem.

Comment: Having said that it is also very nice to feel appreciated - that can come from both you colleagues and also the managers.

Comment: @EdHeal not something people normally would walk out the door for giving no notice though, there's usually something nasty behind that.

Comment: @killsi - It has been known.